# How to search for value in JTable column wise

Tags: java

There are three textFields and search buttons:

- text_productName.
- text_UnitPrice.
- text_Qty

1. If I select text in combobox listproduct and click on search button then only JTable productName column under only search.
2. If I enter text in text_UnitPrice and click on search button then only JTable UnitPrice column under only search.
3. If I enter text in text_Qty and click on search button then only JTable Qty column under only search.

```
package suncomputer;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.RowFilter;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

public class ViewStock extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    Vector originalTableModel;
    DocumentListener documentListener;
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
    JTable table=null;
    Vector<Product> allStock=null;
    boolean flag=true;
    JLabel labelProductName=new JLabel("Product Name");
    JComboBox listProduct=new JComboBox();
    JLabel labelUnitPrice=new JLabel("Unit Price");
    JTextField textUnitPrice=new JTextField(20);
    JLabel labelQty=new JLabel("Qty");
    JTextField textQty=new JTextField(20);
    JCheckBox searchOnType=new JCheckBox("Search On Type");
    JButton button_search=new JButton("Search");
    public ViewStock() {
        JPanel newPanelSearch = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints constraints_search = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints_search.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        constraints_search.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);

        // add components to the panel
        constraints_search.gridx = 0;
        constraints_search.gridy = 0;       
        newPanelSearch.add(labelProductName, constraints_search);

        constraints_search.gridx = 1;
        newPanelSearch.add(listProduct, constraints_search);

        constraints_search.gridx = 0;
        constraints_search.gridy = 1;       
        newPanelSearch.add(labelUnitPrice, constraints_search);

        constraints_search.gridx = 1;
        newPanelSearch.add(textUnitPrice, constraints_search);

                constraints_search.gridx = 0;
        constraints_search.gridy = 2;       
        newPanelSearch.add(labelQty, constraints_search);

        constraints_search.gridx = 1;
        newPanelSearch.add(textQty, constraints_search);

                constraints_search.gridx=3;
                newPanelSearch.add(button_search,constraints_search);
                constraints_search.gridx=8;
                newPanelSearch.add(searchOnType,constraints_search);
                newPanelSearch.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
                BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(), "Product Search"));

        // add the panel to this frame
        this.add(newPanelSearch,BorderLayout.NORTH);

                button_search.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               searchTableContents(textUnitPrice.getText());
            }
        });
        //initComponents();
          this.setTitle("Stock Details");
          commonMethod comonmethod=new commonMethod();
          allStock= comonmethod.viewStock();
          if(allStock != null ){
          JPanel newPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        constraints.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
                if(flag){
                 model.addColumn("Product Id");
                 model.addColumn("Company Name");
                 model.addColumn("Product Name");
                 model.addColumn("Qty");
                 model.addColumn("Rate");
                 table = new JTable(model);
                 flag=false;
                }
                model=(DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
                 System.out.println("list size"+allStock.size());
                for(int i=0;i<allStock.size();i++){            
                    Product product=new Product();
                    product=allStock.get(i);
                    Vector<Object> customer=new Vector<Object>();
                    customer.add(product.getProductid());
                    customer.add(product.getCompanyName());
                    listProduct.addItem(product.getProductName());
                    customer.add(product.getProductName());
                    customer.add(product.getQty());
                    customer.add(product.getRate());
                    model.addRow(customer);
                }
                JScrollPane scrollpane=new JScrollPane(table);
                this.add(newPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                this.add(scrollpane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
                Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
                this.setBounds(0,0,screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
                this.setVisible(true);
                this.pack();
          }else
          {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,"Stock Not Available");
          }
          searchOnType.setText("Search on Type");
          searchOnType.addItemListener(new java.awt.event.ItemListener() {
                public void itemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
                    searchOnTypeItemStateChanged(evt);
                }
            });
          originalTableModel = (Vector) ((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).getDataVector().clone();
          addDocumentListener();
    }
    public void searchTableContents(String searchString) {
    DefaultTableModel currtableModel = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    //To empty the table before search
    currtableModel.setRowCount(0);
    //To search for contents from original table content
    for (Object rows : originalTableModel) {
        Vector rowVector = (Vector) rows;
        for (Object column : rowVector) {
            if (column.toString().contains(searchString)) {
                //content found so adding to table
                currtableModel.addRow(rowVector);
                break;
            }
        }

    }
}
    private void addDocumentListener() {
    documentListener = new DocumentListener() {
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent) {
            search();
        }

        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent) {
            search();
        }

        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent) {
            search();
        }

        private void search() {
            searchTableContents(textUnitPrice.getText());
        }
    };
    searchOnType.setSelected(true);
}
private void searchOnTypeItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                              
    if (searchOnType.isSelected()) {
        textUnitPrice.getDocument().addDocumentListener(documentListener);
    } else {
        textUnitPrice.getDocument().addDocumentListener(null);
    }
}
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                                           
}
```

### Output looks like this:

[image: screen shot]

If I select any product then the table should display only this product record.

If I enter Unitprice then this record only should display.

If I enter only qty then this qty record only should display.

If I enter productname and qty then this productname and qty record should display.

If I enter unitprice and qty then this unitprice and qty record should display.

Comment: please help  me to solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use a RowFilter, which is explained [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/RowFilter.html)

Comment: RowFileter is used for row wise filtering and my requirement is column wise filter

Comment: (1+) `RowFileter is used for row wise filtering and my requirement is column wise filter` - a RowFilter is used to filter rows based on the data in a specific colulmn, which is exactly what you are asking. Check out the [Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) example from the Swing tutorial.